# Understanding `conda install` (channel and packages)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install [fastai](https://github.com/fastai/fastai) but I don't understand what they are trying to do with `conda install`.

The [man page](https://github.com/fastai/fastai) of `fastai` says:

```
conda install -c fastai -c pytorch -c anaconda fastai gh anaconda
```

**Does this mean:** the channels to be used are `fastai`, `pytorch` and `anaconda` while the packages to be installed are `fastai`, `gh` and `anaconda` respectively? I think they want to install `pytorch` and `fastai` basically. But they don't even mention `pytorch` package.

`conda install` seems to be done like this:

```
conda install -c <package-name>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty much it. I would translate the command

```
conda install -c fastai -c pytorch -c anaconda fastai gh anaconda
```

as the imperative sentence

> *While prioritizing the Anaconda Cloud channels **fastai**, **pytorch**, and **anaconda**, in that order, ensure that the current environment has some version of each of the packages `fastai`, `gh`, and `anaconda` installed.*

Channels tell Conda where to search for packages, and the order gives priority (first > last). Since URLs are not given, but only channel names (e.g., `pytorch`), Conda will assume these channels are hosted on Anaconda Cloud (e.g., [PyTorch channel](https://anaconda.org/pytorch)). Everything that is not parseable as an option (e.g., `-c`) or an argument to an option (`pytorch`) is interpreted as a package to be installed (e.g., `gh`).

### PyTorch

As for `pytorch` not being mentioned, it is listed as a dependency of the `fastai` package:

```bash
$ conda search --info -c fastai fastai=2.0.13
Loading channels: done
fastai 2.0.13 py_0
------------------
file name   : fastai-2.0.13-py_0.tar.bz2
name        : fastai
version     : 2.0.13
build       : py_0
build number: 0
size        : 141 KB
license     : Apache Software
subdir      : noarch
url         : https://conda.anaconda.org/fastai/noarch/fastai-2.0.13-py_0.tar.bz2
md5         : bca97ff1932c61aeed960d9cd8dea9fc
timestamp   : 2020-09-17 04:24:42 UTC
dependencies: 
  - fastcore >=1.0.5
  - fastprogress >=0.2.4
  - matplotlib
  - packaging
  - pandas
  - pillow
  - pip
  - python
  - pytorch >=1.6.0
  - pyyaml
  - requests
  - scikit-learn
  - scipy
  - spacy
  - torchvision >=0.7
```

so it doesn't need an explicit specification in the installation command.

### Minimal Environment

I would note that unless you need the full Anaconda distribution in the environment, I would instead encourage using a more minimal installation and keep it in a dedicated environment, e.g.,

```bash
conda create --name my_fastai_env -c fastai -c pytorch -c anaconda fastai
```

which will still provide everything in `fastai`, without all the extra packages that come by default in the `anaconda` metapackage.

Comment: Finally some clarity. Thank you very much. One small follow up: why am I supposed to install `anaconda`? Don't I have `anaconda` already? To use `conda install` you need `anaconda` don't you? @merv

Comment: @ThejKiran Conda (the package and environment manager) is distinct from Anaconda, which is a distribution of a bunch of common data science tools and includes the `conda` package. I'm not entirely clear on the motivation for including `anaconda` package. The docs seem to conflate having an Anaconda base installed with always wanting to install `anaconda` (unlikely), and a Miniconda base with not wanting `anaconda` (usually true). Since both include Conda, both allow bespoke environments with or without `anaconda`. Perhaps it is a safeguard to make sure `anaconda` updates?

Comment: so you are saying that installing `anaconda` the package might not be necessary as the `miniconda` installation does not require `anaconda` the package?

Comment: The `anaconda` package is not required to install `fastai`, whether you have an Anaconda or Miniconda **base**. The "Minimal Environment" I suggest is what I regard as a better practice than the commands they suggest. However, beginners often want everything installed by default, and so may prefer including `anaconda`.

Comment: **A note:** Installing fastai and pytorch in the already installed anaconda seems to raise so many conflicts (which I do not know how to handle). Going with the minimalistic approach got me 0 error or warning messages. :)