# Installing fastai in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, fast-ai

I'm trying to install fastai in anaconda on my laptop, but it's always returning `solving environment:failed...` for every thing I tried.

I tried using all of these: `conda install -c fastai fastai` , `conda install -c fastai -c pytorch fastai` ,  `conda install -c fastai -c pytorch -c anaconda fastai gh anaconda`. In the case of the last one, it returned me that there was no 'gh' available to keep going with the installation. I don't know what else to try to solve this, can anyone help me please?

Comment: The issue is with conda and not fastai. Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266535/conda-returns-solving-environment-failed

Comment: Oh, i didn't see this one, i'll take a look, thank you so much

Comment: it's not working, i tried the approches there, but nothing working

Comment: Have you tried upgrading all of your conda packages? It would help more if you had a larger stacktrace to show us

Answer (score 4):

I was able to install fastai in Anaconda using the following command:

```
conda install -c fastai -c pytorch -c anaconda -c conda-forge fastai gh anaconda
```

The package gh is available in **conda-forge**, and added that as the last channel to look for packages.  Here is a good [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64056502/understanding-conda-install-channel-and-packages) explaining the command.

A few notes about my setup:

- Windows 10
- Conda 4.8.3, Anaconda Navigator 1.9.12 (Installed last week)

The steps I went through:

1. I created a new environment in Navigator->Environments
2. Selected the new environment
3. Had to install Conda Powershell in the new env,
   (Navigator indicates this)
4. Opened a Conda Powershell from navigator
5. Then ran the command above

It took a while to complete and I was prompted with a question (see image) and entered 'y'

[image: question prompted by the install]